# Problema no arquivo OiMundoServlet.java - #algaworks

Tags: java, java-ee, apache, maven

Estou seguindo o E-book "Java EE7 Com JSF, PrimeFaces e CDI". Criei o projeto Maven, editei o arquivo `pom.xml` como a apostila orienta, ao criar o arquivo de exemplo `OiMundoServlet.java`, verifiquei que apareceu os erros que a apostila informa, mas ao editar novamente o arquivo `pom.xml` para eliminar os erros, esses mesmos erros não sumiram. Como corrigir isso?

- Nota 1: estou usando a ultima versão do Eclipse Java EE(Mars.1 Release (4.5.1))
- Nota 2: Quando adicionei o server apache 8, ao vincular o projeto Maven acusou o seguinte erro: **`Project facet Java version 1.8 is not supported`**.
- Nota 3: O arquivo `web.xml` não foi criado automaticamente. Tive que criá-lo pois acusava um erro no arquivo `pom.xml` na linha referente ao `<packaging>war</packaging>`.

Segue o código:

```
package br.com.farmsystem.servlet;//essa linha apresenta erro

import java.io.IOException;//essa linha apresenta erro
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class OiMundoServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/oi-mundo")
public class OiMundoServlet extends HttpServlet { //essa linha apresenta erro

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public OiMundoServlet() {
        super();//essa linha apresenta erro
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {//essa linha apresenta erro
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {//essa linha apresenta erro
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para a ultima versão da plataforma *Java EE 7*, o `web.xml` não é mais obrigatório, é opicional.

Mas por via das dúvidas, escolher utilizar por motivos como configurações de outros frameworks, pode-se utilizar a ultima versão do servlet (3.1).

**Servlet 3.1 - Descriptor**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

No eclipse, ao adicionar um novo servidor na aba `New Server`, caso escolher **Apache Tomcat 8**, clique no botão `Add`, em JRE escolha a versão 8 do *Java*, mas antes certifique-se que em sua maquina, você tem a ultima versão do *Java* instalado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra alternativa, é ir em `Properties` do projeto, em `Project Facets` na aba `Runtime` botão `New` e escolher o servidor de aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Certifique-se também que em `Project Facets` é a versão `1.8` do Java.

No `pom.xml` para especificar a versão 8 do Java, pode ser feito pelo `maven-compiler-plugin`

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

E para deixar explicito para o *Maven* que o `web.xml` não precisa ser verificado ou detectado, pode ser feito através do `maven-war-plugin` assim não irá gerar nenhum erro, caso o mesmo não exista.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.6</version>
     <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> Outros descriptors - Java EE 7

http://antoniogoncalves.org/2013/06/04/java-ee-7-deployment-descriptors/

Answer (score 0):

Vê se isto te ajuda.
Criando a pasta WEB-INF e o arquivo web.xml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

> erro: Project facet Java version 1.8 is not supported.

Qual versão do java você usa? 
para descobrir: no terminal digite `java -version`. Altere o `pom.xml` de acordo com a versão que você utiliza.

Ex.: `java -version -> 1.7.x`

no `pom.xml`: substitua as referências do `java 1.8` para `1.7`